# Solr: get the incorrect numfound when query

Tags: solr, numbers

I have tried to get the number of results when I used Solr-Cluster,here is the query link

```
select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true
```

So I got such result with json

```
  "response":{"numFound":35851492,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":
```

but when I wrote another query like this

```
select?q=*%3A*&start=100000&wt=json&indent=true
```

I got another numfound

```
 "response":{"numFound":35850348,"start":100000,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":
```

Now I want to get why there are different numfound in the same data and how can I get the correct numfound for my application! thank you!

Comment: You sure no updates happened between the 2 queries?

Comment: yeah,I'm sure that I did nothing.Because it is a static experiment workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried to get the number of results when I used Solr-Cluster

This is the key.  It has nothing to do with "rows", and everything to do with querying a cluster.
The internal load balancing is probably picking a different shard, and the shard replicas must not have identical data.

You can try querying the shards individually (and also passing the param distrib=false to avoid distributed search and query that shard only).